# Android screen in the home of the device

Tags: java, android

[image]

How can I create a similar thing for android?

In short, when you click on the app icon, this window opens.

I tried to look, but I do not know what term to use to find a basic example.

Some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a transparent activity. Create a custom style in style.xml as below;

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

And use it in your Manifest.xml application or activity section

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Then, of course, you need to create a layout with a background color at the center of activity and put your views in it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this hack, although I think it's done more as a service.

Because in the image I posted, if I click outside, in the transparent part, it closes app.
Do you think you can do something like that?

P.Š.
If I wanted to make the rounded corners, how in the image how could I do?

Comment: No need to make a special thing to handle click events at the transparent part of the activity. Just listen click event on activity and close application. And for rounded corners, use a cardView as a container and set its cornerRadius value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a floating view backed by a Service (because it's not part of your app's main Activity flows).

Comment: I'm not very sure I got it right, so it's an independent flow, a service, right?
What can I look for to find an example?